# how to convert element at index 1 to upper() in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I convert each element at index 1 in the inner list to upper() using only list comprehension.

```
ed_sheeran = [ [j.upper() for j[1] in i ] for i in ed_sheeran ] # My code but not working.


ed_sheeran =  [[' ', 'w', 'h', 'i', 't', 'e', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'p', 's', ',', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e', ' '], [' ', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 's', 'n', 'o', 'w', 'f', 'l', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' '], [' ', 'b', 'u', 'r', 'n', 't', ' ', 'l', 'u', 'n', 'g', 's', ' ', 's', 'o', 'u', 'r', ' ', 't', 'a', 's', 't', 'e', ' ']]

for i in ed_sheeran:
    i[1] = i[1].upper()    
print(ed_sheeran)

Output: 
[[' ', 'W', 'h', 'i', 't', 'e', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'p', 's', ',', ' ', 'p', 'a', 'l', 'e', ' ', 'f', 'a', 'c', 'e', ' '], [' ', 'B', 'r', 'e', 'a', 't', 'h', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'i', 'n', ' ', 's', 'n', 'o', 'w', 'f', 'l', 'a', 'k', 'e', 's', ' '], [' ', 'B', 'u', 'r', 'n', 't', ' ', 'l', 'u', 'n', 'g', 's', ' ', 's', 'o', 'u', 'r', ' ', 't', 'a', 's', 't', 'e', ' ']]
```

Comment: @HolyDanna Not only does he post his attempt, he posts a working version just not using a list comprehension.  This is a perfectly fine question.

Comment: @HolyDanna read the question, OP already wrote what he tried via list comprehension. He even commented "# My code but not working."

Comment: Why do you need to use a list comprehension? It's more efficient and more readable to just do this in a loop, which you can do on one line if you're determined: `for e in en_sheeran: e[1] = e[1].upper()`

Comment: @MoxieBall I just wanted to see how it works using list comprehensions in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to stitch together the other parts of the list ensuring that all elements are in lists.

```
[[x[0], x[1].upper()] +  x[2:] for x in ed_sheeran]
```

Comment: @MoxieBall fair enough. I updated it but I wanted to draw it out for explanatory purposes.

Comment: This almost works as is with a list of strings as well - so you can work with a list of strings instead of a list of lists to start with. It just have to be written in a way to work with generic sequences instead:

`[x[0] + x[1].upper() + x[2:] for string in mylist]`

Answer (score 3):

Just enumerate the sub lists and change individual elements to upper if index value is 1

```
[[y.upper() if i==1 else y for i,y in enumerate(x)]  for x in ed_sheeran]
```

Comment: can I know what is enumerate? is it a function related to loops?

Comment: Yes - for each item in the sequence, it yields the item index and the item itself, and you get both available in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

`.upper()` will return a new string, not update it inplace - and, on the other hand, the attribution statement `=` is not meant to be used inside expressions such as list comprehensions.

Replacing a list element is possible in an expression, though, if one call the `__setitem__` method on the list, which is ordinarily done by the `=`. If one wants to "look clean" by not calling the dunder `__setitem__` methos directly, it is possible to use `operator.setitem`  to do that as an expression:

```
from operator import setitem
ed_sheeran = [setitem(part, 1, part[1].upper()) for part in ed_sheeran ]
```

Or, if you prefer without importing `setitem`:

```
ed_sheeran = [part.__setitem__(1, part[1].upper()) for part in ed_sheeran]
```

Actually, this is done inplace, so you don't even need to re-assign the outter-list - although if you don't want to create a new-list in memory, and use a generator expression you will need to "consume" the generator. The "any" built-in is a nice one in this case:

```
any(part.__setitem__(1, part[1].upper()) for part in ed_sheeran)
```

(this works only because `__setitem__` returns None)